# Xdebug and PhpStorm cannot step in private method when PHP is run in docker container

Tags: php, docker, intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm running Apache with PHP and Xdebug in a docker container and debugging works insofar that I can set breakpoints in the code and the debugger stops at these breakpoints. PhpStorm/IntelliJ IDEA is run from the host system. However when I try to step inside a private method of the current class, I get an exception like this:

```text
Call to private method MyClass::myMethod() from context ''
```

I think I set up the path mappings correctly in PhpStorm, otherwise I would assume the debugger would not work at all. The absolute path of the project directory on the host system is mapped to the absolute path within the container.

It seems to be a problem that the context is `''` while debugging. Is there a way to inspect the current context? Am I missing a required setting for this to work inside a docker container?